# how to make li slide-in and out on hover?

Tags: css

How can i make the li's slide-in/out on hover?
I tried to add to li negative left value and then on hover set left to zero, but it didn't work for me.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">EN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RU</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    display:;
}

.menu li {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.6s linear;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu li:first-child {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}

.menu ul:hover > li {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/53fs3sdq/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what you had in mind? Utilises `transform`: https://jsfiddle.net/2u8dt4s2/

Comment: Yes, thank you that's exactly what i wanted, one more question, li elements are showing if i hover near them, but its actually should appear after hovering exactly on the li element.

Comment: You need to inspect element and check out how the element is rendering. For example, you're hovering whenever `ul` is hovered which encompasses all `li` children as well as some padding on the left.